# how to change date format in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

The data in tables stores as mm/dd/yyyy (and for example it's like 3/11/2000 not 03/11/2000), but I want it in format as yyyy-mm-dd, how do I do that?
Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Do you need to do everything in SQL queries, or do you have access to external libraries / languages ? Accessing the data externally have some advantages, like being able to treat the strings as/with regular expressions, reformat the date, and write it back. SQLite is limited in such functions, or the solution will be more of a hack.

Comment: I just started to learn sql and after i imported this csv file, the date is like this format (mm/dd/yyyy). I don't know about external libraries but I do know r code. (only a little tho) I was thinking changing the date format before imported into sqlite but I don't know how ;(